# wordpress redirecting admin login to admin login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

this is my last resort as I have been developing wordpress for a few years and have never come accross this.

All the blog and its categories and sub categories all work fine and are visible yet when I go to login in the admin area, if I type in incorrect credentials it sends me back with the error. If I put in the correct credentials it redirects me back to the same page without any error... basically I cannot login with the correct credentials.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before. I have done research on the site urls being incorrect in the options table but they are all correct and as I say the site is visible.

regards

Comment: What theme/version are you using?

Comment: have u tried to check the url if it has www/non-www? Also try manually changing the pass using phpmyadmin.

Comment: @jc - have done and used the update_option() function in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in using http://domain.com/wp-login.php instead of http://domain.com/wp-admin/